# my postman don't send data via post to restful api but others do (after installing passport)

Tags: php, laravel, postman, laravel-6

I can't send my data via post method in postman.
1- my postman is a native app.
2- my routes are absolutely correct as you can see below.
3- I'm using API resource in api.php and when I send data with post store function didn't run.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjAkt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBZ3b.png)

in my controller everything is fine but every time I call the API index method ran.
All of my routes have this problem, it looks like post data from my pc have been ignored.

thanks for your support.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15807#issuecomment-252695360) will help.

Comment: Or try removing the trailing slash at the end of your Postman request. Change `api/author/` to `api/author`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel sometimes has an issue with trailing slashes at the end of your URL.

Try removing it:

Change this:

```
AnurBuk.naeimsafaee.ir/api/author/
```

To this:

```
AnurBuk.naeimsafaee.ir/api/author
```

Comment: in my case that was the problem